# reload router component on same navigation click - refresh page on nav click

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, angular-routing

I have a page with `navbar` which loads child components using lazy loading. Now when I try to click the `nav` for the same page/url, angular does nothing(which is default behaviour). I need the `nav` to reload so that if user has selected any filters on the page, they will be cleared. Thus giving refresh functionality on navigation bar click.

I used `onSameUrlNavigation`: 'reload', But it does not work.

My parent route file **app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'option1', loadChildren: './featureModules/option1/option1.module#option1Module', canActivate:[ActivateRouteGaurd]   },                                            
  { path: 'option2', loadChildren: './featureModules/option2/option2.module#option2Module', canActivate:[ActivateRouteGaurd]   },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true, onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

my child router looks like this. **option1-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'nav1', component: Nav1Component },
  { path: 'nav1/details/:id', component: ViewComponent }, 
  { path: 'nav2', component: Nav2Component },
  { path: 'nav2/details/:id', component: ViewComponent},
  { path: 'nav3', component: Nav3Component },
  { path: 'nav3/add', component: AddComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'user', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

I have searched a lot on this but nothing seems to work. I am not sure if this can be implemented from component since `navbar` is a different component and is included in the component.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add minimal, reproducible example on stackblitz.com.

Comment: stackblitz is restricted for me.

Comment: try plnk or https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Have you tried using JavaScript's `location.reload()` method? See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) for documentation

Comment: It appears there is a ticket open for this issue. The route reloads but the components do not. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21115

Comment: I cannot use location.reload() since I only need to reload component and not the page. @sudo_kaizen I am restricted to use any online code managers.

Comment: @RockySims: thanks for the ticket but is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone for the help. Using your ideas I found a workaround.

```
    const that = this;
    const path = this.location.path();
    $('.navbar-nav li.nav-nav1').on('click', function (e) {
      that.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() =>
          that.router.navigate([path])
      );
    });

This is taking my page to other url and then to my url which tricks angular to reload the component.
```

Comment: Is that jQuery in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

How is this method

```
<a [routerLink]="path" (click)="reload()">aaa</a>
<router-outlet *ngIf="view"></router-outlet>
```

```
reload(){
  this.view=false;
  setTimeout(()=>this.view=true);
}
```